# How to sort a dictionary which is given in a list

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

I have to write a function that let you add a new planet as a dictionary to a list. The problem  is that the list have to be sorted.
So for example for `input: name = Earth` the output would be:`{'name': 'Earth', 'density': '123.123'}]  [{'name': 'Mars', 'density': 5.427}, {'name': 'Venus', 'density': 5.513},`
instead of: `[{'name': 'Mars', 'density': 5.427}, {'name': 'Venus', 'density': 5.513}, {'name': 'Earth', 'density': '123.123'}]`

```
My code:
base = [
    {"name": "Mars", "density": 5.427},
    {"name": "Venus", "density": 5.513},
]
name = input("Enter the name of the planet: ")
destiny = input("Enter the density of the planet: ")


def addPlanet(name, destiny, base):
    new_planet = {"name": name, "density": destiny}
    base.append(new_planet)
    return base


addPlanet(name, destiny, base)
print(base)
```

Comment: Sorted according to what rule?

Comment: Alphabetic order

Comment: According to the `name` values?

Comment: Yes, accroding to the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like that without the sort function:

```
def addPlanet(name, destiny, base):
    # Cast to float
    new_planet = {"name": name, "density": float(destiny)}
    index = 0
    # Find where to place the new_planet
    while name > base[index]["name"]:
        index += 1
    # Insert it and move other planets by one
    for i in range(index, len(base)):
        temp = base[i]
        base[i] = new_planet
        new_planet = temp
    # For the last one append to increase the size of the array
    base.append(temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

just add `base.sort(key=lambda x: x['name'])` after your `addPlanet()`.

BTW, you function does not must to get and return `base` as it is global.

Comment: Can it be made without using sort func?

Comment: do you mean to sort without using the built-in sort()?

Comment: Yes, without the sort() and sorted()

Comment: well, you can transverse your list, as long as your name > current_name. and then use `insert` to enter your new dict into that position

Comment: Lior ata ah yakar!

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you have numbers (float) for the base densities. But, when you insert a new one, you are not transforming the string to float.

So, it is missing a `float(density)` or as below:

```
density = float(input("Enter the density of the planet: "))
```

**Note**: This is trusting that the user typed a number, not a name. In other words, if the user type, for example, `test`, it will generate an exception

Also, it is not a problem, but you named the variable `destiny` instead of `density`.

To print it in order, you can:

```
# Sort by name
print(sorted(base, key=lambda p: p["name"]))

# Sort by density
print(sorted(base, key=lambda p: p["density"]))
```

Also, you could use a function for that

```
def sort_by_name(x):
    return x["name"]

def sort_by_density(x):
    return x["density"]

# Sort by name
print(sorted(base, key=sort_by_name))

# Sort by density
print(sorted(base, key=sort_by_density))
```